# PHP class use - undefined variable error

Tags: php, class, parameters

Two files:
- Login.php
- Registration.

Login.php has two variables.
Registration.php has three.

Login.php has only two variables, however the class is using three variables, and returning the error when method's invoked, that variable's undefined.

Please, if above explanation gives no idea read the comments in the code.

**Registration.php**

```
 include("validate_class.php");
    //Fields in registration
    $username                    = "";
    $password                    = "brokenship";
    $email                        = "sami@hotmail.com";

    //Instantiating my class.
    $instantiateClass            = new validate_class($username, $password, $email);

    //This is called in registration.php file. This validates the three fields registration.php has. $email, $password, 
    $instantiateClass->validate_empty();
```

**Login.php**

```
include("validate_class.php");
//Fields in login
$username                   = "";
$password                   = "brokenship";

//Instantiating my class.
$instantiateClass           = new validate_class($username, $password, $email);

//This is called in registration.php file. This validates the three fields registration.php has. $email, $password, 
$instantiateClass->validate_empty();

//*****Now, here's the problem. I wanna only give two parameters..*****//
```

**validate_class.php**

```
class validate_class {
    function __construct($username, $password, $email){

        //Regular value
        $this->username                         = $username;
        $this->password                         = $password;
        $this->email                            = $email;

        //Add empty function
        $this->empty_username                   = empty($username);
        $this->empty_password                   = empty($password);
        $this->empty_email                      = empty($email);
    }

    function validate_empty(){
        if( ($this->empty_username) or ($this->empty_password) or ($this->empty_email) ){
            echo "Fill all the fields";
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: @class  $instantiateClass   = new validate_class($username, $password, $email);

Says there's undefined variable($email) in that line. Check the login.php file above please.

Comment: I don't get it. It says `$email` is undefined because it is undefined. What's your question? What do you mean `I wanna only give two parameters`?

Comment: Mark M As you can see I'm want the login.php form to be validated too. However since it only has two variable that need to be validated I cannot give it the third variable. And therefore it returns an error. Point is I cannot give it third argument since it does not exist.

Comment: You could pass an empty string or false, or set a default value of `$email` in the constructor. The problem, though, is that `validate_empty()` will fail if there is no email, so you need to alter that to work for both login and registration, or create two functions, `validate_empty_login` and `validate_empty_registration` or something like that.

Comment: Mark M Would it be a good idea to extend the class and then add functions necessary for login validation?

Comment: I don't think it would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shows the hint if no email provided:

```
class validate_class {
function __construct($username, $password, $email=false){

    //Regular value
    $this->username                         = $username;
    $this->password                         = $password;
    $this->email                            = $email;

    //Add empty function
    $this->empty_username                   = empty($username);
    $this->empty_password                   = empty($password);
    $this->empty_email                      = $email != false && empty($email);
}

function validate_empty(){
    if( ($this->empty_username) or ($this->empty_password) or ($this->empty_email) ){
        echo "Fill all the fields";
    }
}   
}
```